# Out Of memory issue on post per page parameter

Tags: wp-query, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, memory

I am using woocommerce and i have around 1500 product in one category, i have a brand as a custom taxonomy, and on category page i grab all brands based on product id, Here when i pass post_per_page to -1 it shows out of memory issue,

I have increased memory limit to 500M as well but still same.Here is the code

```
  global $post;
                        global $product;
                        $cate = get_queried_object();
                        $catename = $cate->slug;
                        $category_id = $cate->id;

                        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
                        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>-1, 'product_cat' => $catename, 'orderby' => 'ASC','hide_empty'=> 1 );

                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();                     
                        $termbrand[] = wp_get_post_terms($loop->post->ID,'brand')[0]->term_id;
                        endwhile;
```

it works when i write like, so it can not process more post and take long time.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>1200, 'product_cat' => $catename, 'orderby' => 'ASC','hide_empty'=> 1 );
```

Comment: You can use also `'fields' => 'ids' ` in the arguments to get only the ids. That way you save memory because content etc are not being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try - > 'cache_results' => false**

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' =>-1, 'product_cat' => $catename, 'orderby' => 'ASC','hide_empty'=> 1, 'cache_results' => false );
```